# How do I move my getter to the parent component in Nuxtjs

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a page in Nuxtjs where, on creation I get some data from a vuex store making an axis call to my backend.

In the page I have a sub component that is a table, currently in the sub component I have

computed: {
      ...mapGetters ({
      cases: 'cases/cases',
    }),
   },

in my table I access the results array by

:items=returnedcases

This works fine but I d like to learn how to make the sub component more reusable by moving this code into the parent page.

So how can I move this to the parent page component so I can make the table component reusable?

the table will have pagination and filtering.

From what I have read I can't use props for this so any guidance please on the correct approach would be fantastic

Thanks

Comment: Why you cant use props? There only 2 ways, either use props and pass data from parent to child or to use something like vuex or global vue bus.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have a vuex store set up but I want to return the same results to the parent and the child, I assumed I wouldn't map the getters to both the parent and the child or is that the correct thing to do?

Comment: or if this is completely wrong can you point me to a tutorial or example...thanks

Comment: You can do getters in both parent and child. Although from your description using props in child sound more reasonable.

Comment: ok, great thanks, learnt a bit more, I ll try the props and see if I can get that working, Out of interest is there any negative implications/ performance hit having the same getter in the parent and child?

Comment: there shouldnt be any implications